# css fontsize vmax & vmin together without overwrite / responsive text

Tags: css, html, fonts

Is there a way to use vmax and vmin together on the same element so that I can make a rang in which to stop it from getting to small or to big? When I use just one it will get to big or way to small Im trying to limit the extremes of both sides of it. This is for use with responsive design.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sc8gm/29/

```
<p>Here is some paragraph text at 3 vmin</p>
<h1>Here is some paragraph text at 3 vmin</h1>
<style>
    p {font-size: 3vmax;}
    h1 {font-size: 3vmin;font-size:4vmax;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, kind of. See fiddle at the bottom.

You can smooth out the response curve.

Can do this for css/style:

```
font-size: calc(3 * (0.5vw + 0.5vh));
```

Can also do this in html or body of document css or style:

```
--size: calc(0.5vmax + 0.5vmin);
```

and then use variable in css or style of element you want to change with scaling set by initial number like `3.0 *`:

```
font-size: calc(3.0 * var(--size));
```

This way you can then redefine the response curve separately from each element's relative size and is simpler to read with a single scaling number per element.

Note (0.5vw + 0.5vh) does same thing as (0.5vmin + 0.5vmax) by averaging both lengths for simplicity.

Additionally you can increase or decrease importance of each differently. (0.2vmin + 0.8vmax) would respond weaker to smallest side of window but respond stronger to largest side of window, so text not get too small when window becomes too small but might get too big when window is too big. Alternatively you could reduce dependence only on specific side of window so (0.2vh + 0.8vw) would scale text less when y-axis is shrunk (like when android keyboard pops out) but on too wide screens might grow too large (is that even common?).

var and calc browser compatibility is very good (see bottom): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

other native css commands like max/min/clamp are far less compatible.

https://jsfiddle.net/xsmhcpL4/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use two `font-sizing` property definitions. The last one will override your first. To answer your question there is no `max-font-size` property:

> As with fluid images, the power of responsive text is double-edged: it’s entirely possible for hero text scaled with vw and vh units become too large or small at extreme screen sizes. Sadly, there’s no max-font-size property to govern this behavior, although the CSS3 min() and max() functions will fill the role nicely once they are supported by browsers.

[source](http://demosthenes.info/blog/739/Creating-Responsive-Hero-Text-With-vw-Units)